# usb windriver API

Tags: visual-studio-2008

sample code of reading data from usb port in C#.net by windriver API

Comment: You need to give more detail on your USB device and the API. Also, this isn't Google, we'll understand better if you phrase your request as question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by windriver API you mean the WinDriver product by Jungo. If you go to this page [Sample Code (WinDriver)](http://www.jungo.com/st/support/techissues-samplecode.html) it says that there should be C# samples installed when you install the toolkit itself.
I've never used WinDriver myself but I'd suggest you go searching through the installed files and see what you find.

Otherwise, if you're just looking for generic C# code to communicate with a USB device and assuming it's a HID, you can find an article on codeproject that should be helpful: [A USB HID Component for C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/USB_HID.aspx)